# why .catch is getting executed before executor completes its task?

Tags: node.js, promise

after running the below code, I have mentioned the output I got in console.
As per my understanding as soon as promise is defined, executor completes its task, .then and .catch executes only then. But below results indicates that .catch is getting executed before executor runs. Can anyone please help?

code:

```
var dbconnect = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    mongoClient.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (error, db) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Database connection failed')
            reject(Error('Database Connection Failed'))
        } else {
            console.log('Database connected')
            resolve(db)
        }
    })
});

dbconnect
.then(
    db => {
         console.log('db value :', db);
    },
    error => {
        console.log('connection failed :', error)
    }
)
.catch(
    console.log('exception handling')
);
```

output:
exception handling

Database connected

db value : MongoClient {
  domain: null,

Comment: FWIW: [`MongoClient.connect`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/MongoClient.html#connect) returns a Promise itself, so wrapping it with a `new Promise` is superfluous.

Answer (score 5):

`.catch` accepts a *function* as a parameter. When you do

```
.catch(
    console.log('exception handling')
);
```

the interpreter *immediately* calls `console.log` there in an attempt to get a function out of it, so that the function can be put into the `Promise` chain, so that it can be called if there's an error that needs to be caught. For behavior to be more as expected, change to:

```
.catch(() => {
  console.log('exception handling')
});
```

But the other problem is that *all* errors will currently be "caught" above, in your `.then`'s error handler (second function passed to `.then`):

```js
const mongoClient = { connect: (_, __, fn) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    fn('some error');
  }, 500);
}};

var dbconnect = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    mongoClient.connect('db', { useNewUrlParser: true }, (error, db) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Database connection failed')
            reject(Error('Database Connection Failed'))
        } else {
            console.log('Database connected')
            resolve(db)
        }
    })
});

dbconnect
.then(
    db => {
         console.log('db value :', db);
    },
    error => {
        console.log('connection failed :', error)
    }
)
.catch(
    () => console.log('exception handling')
);
```

Best to have only a *single* `.catch` location, eg:

```
dbconnect
  .then(
    db => {
      console.log('db value :', db);
    }
  )
  .catch(
    (err) => console.log('exception handling')
  );
```